# stop event and set variable to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

following problem. i have a long scrolling page which adds classes to every div if its in the viewport with inview.js

```
var $div1 = $('#div1');
var $div2 = $('#div2');
//.....
var only_once = 0;

$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').bind('inview', function (event, visible) 
{
    if (visible == true) {
        $(this).addClass("inview");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inview");
    }
});
```

when it adds the class im doing some events and an if condition where something should happen if inview is fired the first time and then stops. i tried it with with switching only_once to 1.

```
if($div1.hasClass("inview")){   
    // here some functions...

    if (only_once == 0) {
        $('.float-second').css('left', 0);
        $('.float-second').css('top', 0);
        only_once = 1;
    } 

    if($div2.hasClass("inview")){   
        // here some functions...


        if (only_once == 1) {
            $('.float-third').css('left', 0);
            $('.float-third').css('top', 0);
            only_once = 2;
        } 
        // and this for the other divs too
```

the problem is, when i do it this way it doesnt fire when the site loads at middle or bottom and im scrolling up or down because of the if condition needs the first events because of its value before.
hope you get my point, how can i do this work well?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem you are having. You can check how much the page is scrolled using:

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

If it's greater than some value that you decide you can call the functions you need to call otherwise if it loads at the top of the page your plugin will do that for you.

Comment: interesting, would you be so nice and show me how? i mean im not that into jquery... a little approach would be nice!

Comment: like `$(document).scrollTop(300){
   fire me something };` ??

Comment: it would something like: if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 300 ) { ... }. Wait is the problem that inview.js isn't firing?

Comment: no the problem is, inview is fireing continuously so this should be fine, i will test it later :)